# read package Name,package AID and Applet AID from capFile

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu, globalplatform

How do i want to get the package AID and applet AID from the cap file?

Currently i am using a tool PyApduTool to get the info of the cap file but right now im trying to create my own tool but got stuck on this step.

Glad if anyone can assists me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Although I have upvoted Shuckey, you really should read the specifications before asking, and if you did read them then please indicate where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [Java Card documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/downloads/default-1970005.html) and look into Java Card Virtual Machine specification. It explains every detail of CAP file format and is (to the best of my knowledge) completely correct and contains just one minor error which is not relevant to you.

Comment: Java Card 3 Platform, Virtual Machine Specification, Classic Edition, Version 3.0.5, May 2015, chapter '6.9 Class Component' incorrectly specifies class_component contains only an array of interface_info structures when in fact this array contains interface_info structures and class_info structures. Smells like this error is dragging from CAP file format 2.1 since there interface_info and class_info structures were cleanly separated.

Answer (score 1):

I tried following approach and succeed:

- Extract .cap file with any zip extractor (for eg WinZip)
- After extraction you will get a MF file (normally named as MANIFEST.MF)
- This file contains all information you are asking for